# Is it possible to create a sub-folder wihtin a library in salesforce?

Tags: content, libraries

To be able to create a hierarchical content structure within the `salesforce` `library` it is necessary to be able to create folders within `folders`. Is this possible or what is the best work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See new app [Folderize](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4caiEAB) on AppExchange.

From the overview:  "Folderize provides the missing folder structure for Salesforce Content Libraries. Create a hierarchy of folders like in a file system; then link documents from existing libraries to one or more subfolders."

Comment: FYI: requires Content.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the type of content you want to put in your folders...

**Code**. Files representing code on the Salesforce.com platform are represented in a mostly flat, folderless structure. In order to represent them on your local disc for development and storage in source control, there is a basic folder structure to categorise, Apex code, Visualforce pages, Object definitions etc. each in its own subfolder. However, [while its a much requested enhancement](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bp88AAC), you cannot currently split your Apex code into sub-folders, the best you can do is using prefixing of the class names. Beyond that, you could use [Packages](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_apps.htm) to further scope and contain your code (using a namespace prefix), however that is in most cases a bit to heavy weight.

[image]

**Documents**. As in images, written documents, pdf's, csv files, general end user files etc. These can be stored in a growing number of ways in Salesforce, **Attachments**, **Chatter Files**, **Content Workspace** and via the **Document** object. This option does permit the organisation of Document records (which represent your files) in a single depth [Folder](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_folder.htm) structure only, no sub-folders are permitted. Note as per the documentation you can also use them to contain other Salesforce components, such as Email Templates.

Comment: Unfortunately I had believed that the answer would be currently negative, my solution is to use the folder strucutre within the package names, so I would have Packages: Folder1-SubFolder1-SubSubFolder1, Folder1-SubFolder1-SubSubFolder2, Folder1-SubFolder2-SubSubFolder1, Folder1-Sub-Folder2-SubSubFolder2, Folder2-SubFolder1-SubSubFolder1, Folder2-SubFolder1-SubSubFolder2.