# Is there a way to split the metadata to custom folders?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

Our org have a huge legacy code base, thousands of classes, VF pages, Lightning pages etc.

We experience a problem that new developers don't know about generic classes and helpers that could be used when they're writing the code and it takes a ton of time on Code Review to find places where a helper could be used, but instead a bicycle is reinvented.

We thought that splitting our huge code base to the folders would be useful and would help us to granular our code and it would help with our problem.
[The only answer I found is 6 years back](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22197/is-it-possible-to-create-a-sub-folder-wihtin-a-library-in-salesforce). So I thought that something could be changed and maybe an ant script or a library invented.

Question is - is there a way to split the metadata by custom folders?

I.E.

```
Core
    classes
        CoreClass1
        CoreClass2
    objects
        Log
        Setting
    ...
MailingTool
    classes
        ...
    pages
        ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the purpose of [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx). The folders won't be on the Salesforce server, but you will be able to organize your folders/packages in a repo. See the [DX Falcon Template](https://github.com/sfdx-isv/sfdx-falcon-template) for an example. Yes, it will take time to convert and organize your source code, but the sooner you get started, the sooner you'll be able to take advantage of this feature.